# How to get the x-value of the max y-value in iOS Charts 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have a LineChartDataSet from which I can get the yMax & yMin values like so:

```
let max = lineDataSet.yMax
let min = lineDataSet.yMin
```

With the older version (2.3) of the Charts Library, I could get the y-values as an array and find the index of the highest value like so:

```
let values = lineDataSet.yVals
let index = values.index(of: yMax)
```

How can I get the x value of the max y-value in the LineChartDataSet?

So if the max value in my DataSet is 100, how can I get the associated x-value?

(The new version 3.0, does not let me get the y-values as an array anymore)

Answer (score 1):

You can still do the same:

```
let entries = lineDataSet.values
let index = entries.map { $0.y }.index(of: yMax)
```

or

```
let entries = lineDataSet.values
let index = entries.index(where: { $0.y == yMax })
```

Comment: thank you for this. i must have missed this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this problem for a bit, this is what I came up with:

```
for i in 0 ..< lineDataSet.entryCount {
    let value = lineDataSet?.entryForIndex(i)
    if value?.y == lineDataSet.yMax {
        xValueOfyMax = (value?.x)!
        break
    }
}
```

The same thing can be done to find the min value.

If you need to find the most recent x-value (since there may be more than one value that matches), you can reverse the for-loop like this:

```
for i in (0 ..< lineDataSet.entryCount).reversed() {
    etc...
}
```